# How to change null values to "Unknown Party" string? using Highcharts

Tags: jquery, json, database, highcharts

This highcharts 3D column chart brings in null values instead of the party type. How can I use the JSON or formatter function settings to change a null value to "Unknown Party" instead of showing the null value on the chart.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var options = {
    // basic chart options
    chart: {
        height: 350,
        renderTo: 'container',
        type: 'column',
        marginRight: 130,
        lang: {
            thousandsSep: ','
        },
        marginBottom: 50,
        style: {
            fontFamily: 'Open Sans'
        },
        // 3D initialization, comment out for non-3D columns
        options3d: {
            enabled: true,
            alpha: 18

        }
    },
    // main chart title (TOP)
    title: {
        text: 'Giving Trends',
        style: {
            fontWeight: 'bold'
        },
        x: -20 //center
    },
    // main chart sub-title (TOP)
    subtitle: {
        text: 'By Party of Filer',
        style: {
            fontWeight: 'bold'
        },
        x: -20
    },
    // xAxis title
    xAxis: {
        labels: {
            style: {
                fontWeight: 'bold',
                color: '#000000'
            }
        },
        reversed: false,
        title: {
            text: 'Party',
            style: {
                fontWeight: 'bold',
                color: '#000000'
            },
            formatter: function () {
                return '<b>' + this.series.name + '</b><br/>' + this.x + ': ' + '$' + Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 0);

            }
        },
        categories: []
    },
    // yAxis title
    yAxis: {
        labels: {
            style: {
                fontWeight: 'bold',
                color: '#000000'
            }
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Dollar Amount',
            style: {
                fontWeight: 'bold',
                color: '#000000'
            }
        },
        // chart options for each plotted point
        plotLines: [{
            value: 1,
            width: 1,
            color: '#000000'
        }]
    },
    // tooltip on hover options
    tooltip: {
        lang: {
            thousandsSep: ','
        },
        formatter: function () {
            return '<b>' + this.series.name + '</b><br/>' + this.x + ': ' + '$' + Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 0);

        }
    },
    legend: {
        layout: 'horizontal',
        align: 'left',
        verticalAlign: 'top',
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
        borderWidth: 0
    },
    plotOptions: {

        allowDecimals: {
            enabled: false
        },
        series: {
            text: 'Total Dollar Amount',
            color: 'rgba(102,131,123, 0.9)',
            fontWeight: 'bold',
            cursor: 'pointer',
            pointWidth: 50
        },
        column: {
            stacking: 'normal',
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.dataLabelsColor) || '',
                formatter: function () {
                    return '$' + Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 0);

                }

            }
        }
    },
    series: []

};

Highcharts.setOptions({
    // sets comma for thousands separator
    lang: {
        thousandsSep: ','
    },
    tooltip: {
        xDecimals: -2 // If you want to add 2 decimals
    }
});


$.getJSON("http://followthemoney.org/charts/data/contributor-data.php?<?php echo $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']; ?>", function (json) {
    options.xAxis.categories = json[0]['data'];
    options.series[0] = json[1];
    chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
    chart.legend.allItems[0].update({
        name: 'Giving Trends by Party'
    }); ///// LEGEND MAIN LABEL CHANGES HERE!

 });

});
```

And this is what I have came up with so far for trying to format the null values, but this snippet of code changes ALL xAxis values to "Not Designated." I am at a loss here trying to format null values, surprises me there is not a similar thread out there.

```
    // xAxis title
   xAxis: {
     labels: {
       formatter: function () {                            
        if(this.name == null)
         return "Not Designated";
       } 
  },
```

Ok, here is the json and data file. Getting close but dont know how to format this so that it checks for a null and then adds the string 'Not Designated'

```
function displayJsonContributorPartyDataChart ($aaQuery) {

        $categories = array();
        $categories['name'] = 'PartyType';

        $series = array();
        $series['name'] = 'AA_Total';

        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $categories['data'][] = $row['PartyType'];
            $series['data'][] = $row['AA_Total'];  
        }

        $result = array();
        array_push($result,$categories);
        array_push($result,$series);

        print json_encode($result, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);

} // END CHART FUNCTION


 $.getJSON("/charts/data/contributor-data.php?<?php echo $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']; ?>", function(json) {
                            options.xAxis.categories = json[0]['data'];
                            // JSON.stringify.categories('data').replace(/null/i, "\"Not Designated\""); 
                            options.series[0] = json[1];
                            chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
                            chart.legend.allItems[0].update({name:'Giving Trends by Party'}); ///// LEGEND MAIN LABEL CHANGES HERE!
                            chart.xAxis.allItems[null].update({name:'Not Designated'}); ///// LEGEND MAIN LABEL CHANGES HERE!


                        });
```

This works! But is adding the 'not designated' string to all xAxis values. How do i make it work on just the null values?

```
labels: {

   formatter: function() {
     if(options.series.name == null) 
        return 'Not Designated';
      } 
  },
```

Thanks again.

Comment: How your data looks like ? Could you recreate your example as live demo on jsfiddle.net?